# Create a multiple price columns or serialize them all

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a "ticket" table on my MySQL database.

I need to store 8 price values. (Example: total price, discount price, etc)

Should i :

1. Create a new column for every price value
2. Store the values in a serialize array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never store data serialized in a database. It is most of the time a pain in the ass because of the fact that no unserialization feature exist in the query engine. Because of that you won't be able to :

- Change it
- Search it
- Consult it

If you want to use a relational database to store multiple/variable quantity of prices like those 8 items you talked about but can have 16, 32, or even 64, then you have to use an adaptive structure that will store each price in a key/value like table that references your previous parent item. This way you can have many prices while not really having a defined structure, this is a high normalization method that usually fixes the issue at hand but doesn't offer quite good performance or scalability!

If you really want to go for an adaptive structure that scales well, consider the no-sql approach such as MongoDB!

Answer (score 1):

One column for each price, you can do queries, calculations, etc right from the queries

Imagine you want all products with discount price > X, you can do that with one query like

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE discount_price > X
```

if you have them serialized on one column you need to get all products, parse them and check the value